# Java Program Calculate Average Using Standard values (code)

Tags: java, average, calculator

I need help about Average calculator....

Q: Given that you have five input values and “average” method, calculate the average value for the five input values inside the average method and return it .

```java
public class MyCalculator {

    int input1 = 10;

    int input2 = 20;

    int input3 = 30;

    int input4 = 40;

    int input5 = 50;

    public float average() {

        // TODO: write java code to calculate the average for all input variables

         return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you've tried to write some code for the `average()` method.  Can you include that code in your question?

Comment: This question came to me this way and i didn't know how to code it . i am new in programming sorry .

Comment: DO your own homework.  We'll help if you've made an honest effort at it and need a nudge to get it over the edge, but we won't do it for you.

Comment: i am sorry for that but i don't understand to do it i tried many times but can't solve it .

Answer (score 0):

The method could look like this:

```
public float average(int input1, int input2, int input3, int input4, int input5) {
     return (input1 + input2 + input3 + input4 + input5 ) / 5;
}
```

Then all you need to do is call average with the five parameters passed to it.

Comment: What if we want to have 100 inputs?

Comment: @michalk That is not what the question asked.